# SpriteKit: Sprites are moving through each other with a physicsBody already set

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody

So I have created a player who moves tile based and a wall surrounding the map to keep the player on the playground. Both have a physicsBody in them. My guess is, that my movement of the player is not properly and so the player bugs into the walls. Let me just show you my code:

So this is the physicsBody of the Player:

```
self.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.House
self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
```

And this is the physicsBody of the Wall:

```
self.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 0
self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
self.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
```

They both inherit from the class Objects:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)
self.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
self.name = name
```

So and just let me give you my code for the movement of the player if thats the cause:

```
func move(direction: String, width: CGFloat){
    //Choosing the direction based of the users touch
    switch direction{
        case "South":
        //Decreasing the position of the player by 1 Tile
        pos.y -= width

        //Flipping the picture the right way to make the player look in the right direction
        yScale = 1.0

        //Rotates the picture
        let rotateAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -1.57, duration: 0.0)
        run(rotateAction)

       //All the other directions just change the x and y value of pos corresponding to the direction
    }

    //Moves the player to the calculated position
    let moveAction =  SKAction.move(to: pos, duration: 0.0)
    run(moveAction){
        //Sound
    }
```

Edit:

The values of the `PhysicsCategory.Player` and `PhysicsCategory.Wall`

```
struct PhysicsCategory{
   static let Wall:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
   static let Player:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
   static let House:UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
}
```

Edit 2:

The main problem is to get collision with SKAction properly working

Comment: What are the values of: PhysicsCategory.Player, PhysicsCategory.House and PhysicsCategory.Wall ?

Comment: Edited. The house is the goal where the player must go to. The same bugs happens there too.

Comment: We're gonna need a much greater mind than mine. Mine's confused.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124357/sprite-kit)

Answer (score 4):

You haven't actually described your problem other than "Sprites are moving through each other..." and "so the player bugs into the walls"

To validate all of your contact and collsions, have a look at my answer here : [iOS SpriteKit - collisions and contacts not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570859/ios-spritekit-collisions-and-contacts-not-working-as-expected/36574240?noredirect=1#comment66724678_36574240) and try implementing the checkPhysics() function and calling it once you think you have set up all of your physics bodies and their interactions.

Are you certain that:

- player and wall actually have physics bodies?
- the scene is an `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`
- You have set `physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self`
- You have implemented one of the optional methods of
     `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`:

  - didBeginContact
  - didEndcontact

Is this correct:

- You want the player to collide with the wall?
- You want the wall to collide with the player?
- You want to be notified    (didBegincontact called) when the player
  and the house touch?
- You don't want to be notified if the wall touches anything?

Comment: Yes I did. Above I linked a chat where I uploaded a video showing the problem. I am going to look at your checkPhysics funktion

Comment: Ah OK - make the chat link a bit more obvious.

Comment: This is a superb run down and checklist of how to get physics working. Wish you were writing Apple's docs!

Answer (score 3):

It is not listed in the question here, but the reason why collision contact is not happening is because the method `didBeginContact` got changed to `didBegin`

Comment: What about the collisons? Was that ok or was there something else?